# python - pandas - grouping together rows occuring at specific dates (from list of dates) and commuting some function on them - how?

Tags: pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

i have a dataframe and a list of specific dates :

```
d = {'case': [1,2,3,4,5], 'registration_datetime': ['2013-01-01 
00:00:16','2013-01-01 00:04:19','2013-01-01 00:12:53','2013-01-02 
00:16:40','2013-01-02 00:21:40'],'discharge_datetime':['2013-01-01 
01:41:02','2013-01-01 04:20:05
','2013-01-01 06:20:22
','2013-01-02 02:01:13
','2013-01-02 05:48:49
']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

spe_dates = DatetimeIndex(['2013-01-01', '2013-01-15',...])
```

my bottom goal is to have a list of the time duration between registration and discharge of each case that registered in one of  the specific dates.

if it wasn't clear , an example; the date '2013-01-01' is in the spe_dates list , so i want to calculate the difference between discharge and register datetime of cases that registered on '2013-01-01' which are cases 1,2,3 and that will be

01:41:02-00:00:16 = 01:40:46 ~ 1.76 hours,

04:20:05-00:04:19=04:15:46 ~ 4.26 hours,

06:20:22-00:12:53=06:07:29 ~ 6.05 hours

then i want to convert it to hours or minutes and have a dataframe (or some other object)  with the list of specific dates (spe_dates) and the relevant durations .

wanted result :

'2013-01-01':[1.76,4.26,6.05]
'2013-01-15':[list of hours calculated in that day]
....

i have no clue how to do this , tried some workarounds with groupby but didn't know how to operate a costume function such as calculating the time between to datetime objects of a certain row

would appreciate any help !

i have no clue how to do this , tried some workarounds with groupby but didn't know how to operate a costume function such as calculating the time between to datetime objects of a certain row

would appreciate any help !